# Get all list items that do not have a data attribute that starts with value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements that each have a data-name attribute.  I want to select all elements that do not start with the prefix "arc" and hide them.

```
<ul id="slides">
  <li data-name="arc_1">...</li>
  <li data-name="arc_2">...</li>
  <li data-name="biz_1">...</li>
  <li data-name="biz_2">...</li>
  <li data-name="cas_1">...</li>
  <li data-name="cas_2">...</li>
  <li data-name="cas_3">...</li>
  <li data-name="prd_1">...</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to use `$('#slides li[data-name^="arc"]')` but it selects the opposite of what it need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('#slides li:not([data-name^="arc"])')
```

```js
$('#slides li:not([data-name^="arc"])').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="slides">
  <li data-name="arc_1">...</li>
  <li data-name="arc_2">...</li>
  <li data-name="biz_1">...</li>
  <li data-name="biz_2">...</li>
  <li data-name="cas_1">...</li>
  <li data-name="cas_2">...</li>
  <li data-name="cas_3">...</li>
  <li data-name="prd_1">...</li>
</ul>
```